# Last id with persistent connection

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently using mysql_pconnect.

Is there a risk of erroneously retrieving the last id inserted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a risk not only with last_insert_id but with transactions and other things.
mysql_pconnect isn't right thing for use it on production because many php instances will have access to a single connection

Answer (score 4):

It seems, according to [this note](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php#31521), that there might be a risk, when the insert query failed *(quoting)* :

> be careful when using
>   `last_insert_id()` with persistent
>   connections - running
>   `last_insert_id()` after a failed
>   update/insert/etc will return the last
>   insert id of the last successful
>   update/insert made by that CONNECTION
>   rather than 0 for the number of rows
>   updated by the previous non-working
>   query